# Length of ciphertext produced by RSAES_OAEP_Encryptor?

Tags: rsa, crypto++

My use of the `Crypto++` library has gone very well, but I have a small question...

If I use `RSAES_OAEP_Encryptor` & `RSAES_OAEP_Decryptor` everything is fine. (I'm using a 2048-bit key from PEM files generated by `OpenSSL`).

My question is this: Will the length of `ciphertext` produced by `encryptor.Encrypt(...)` always equal `decryptor.FixedCiphertextLength()` or can be be less than that? I only ask as this is in a library used by a number of applications and I need to sanity check parameters.....

BTW. Is there any faster was to encrypt/decrypt using RSA which maintains at least the same level of security provided by OAEP? With a 1024 bit key, on an example test box, averaged over 1000 iterations, I'm finding it takes about 80uS to encode a short string and 1.03mS (12 times longer) to decrypt; with a 2048-bit key encryption takes 190uS and decryption, 4.3mS (22 times longer). I know that RSA decryption is slow, but.... the system is running XP Pro SP3/Xeon E5520 and was compiled with VS2008 with /MD rather than /MT. I can't use a shorter key than 2048-bits for compliance reasons...

Many thanks

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Length of ciphertext produced by RSAES_OAEP_Encryptor?

In the case of RSA, I believe `FixedPlaintextLength()` and `FixedCiphertextLength()` call `MaxPreImage()` and `MaxImage()`. `MaxPreImage()` and `MaxImage()`, in turn, returns `n - 1`.

---

> Will the length of ciphertext produced by encryptor.Encrypt(...) always equal decryptor.FixedCiphertextLength() or can be be less than that?

It depends on the cryptosystem being used. Usually, its the size of the key that determines if `FixedCiphertextLength()` holds (and not the size of the plain text). In the case of RSA/OAEP and others like ElGamal, I believe it holds.

I think the class of interest here is the [`PK_CryptoSystem Class Reference`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_p_k___crypto_system.html). Classes like `RSAES_OAEP_Encryptor` inherit from `PK_CryptoSystem`, and that's where `FixedCiphertextLength()` and friends come from.

---

> With a 1024 bit key, on an example test box, averaged over 1000 iterations, I'm finding it takes about 80uS to encode a short string and 1.03mS (12 times longer) to decrypt; with a 2048-bit key encryption takes 190uS and decryption, 4.3mS (22 times longer)

This is a different question, but...

In the case of encryption or verification, the public exponent is used. The public exponent is, by default, 65537 (IIRC). That's got a low hamming weight (high density of 0's), so square and multiply exponentiation routines run relatively fast.

On the other hand, decryption and signing use the private exponent, which should have about a normal distribution of 1's and 0's. There's lots of squares and multiplies to perform, and those take extra time.

Taking advantage of those little timing differences is where your side channels come from if you are not careful. If you are not careful, then the NSA will thank you.

---

> I can't use a shorter key than 2048-bits for compliance reasons

A 2048-bit modulus is about 10x slower than a 1024-bit modulus. Its why so many folks were reluctant to move from 1024-bit, and why 1024-bit is still kind of preferred.

Peter Gutmann has this to say about it in his Engineering Security book (p. 229):

> Another example [of broken threat models] occurred with keys in
>   certificates, for which browser vendors (in response to NIST
>   requirements) forced CAs to switch from 1024-bit to 2048-bit keys,
>   with anything still using 1024-bit keys being publicly denounced as
>   insecure. As discussed in “Problems” on page 1, the bad guys didn’t
>   even notice whether their fraudulent certificates were being signed
>   with, or contained, 2048-bit keys or not.